# css header not displaying above menu

Tags: html, css

i have this css for my header:

and below the header i have a horizontal menu

```
.header {
    height:180px;
    margin-top:0;
    border-top:5px #999999 solid;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-9999;
}
```

the image in the HTML isnt showing - i think its behind the menu and i cant get it above the menu:

ive created a jsFiddle so you can see the full HTML and menu CSS too: http://jsfiddle.net/ar9P6/

Comment: Well... you set the `.header` to have a `position:fixed;` and a low `zindex` so it is always going to be behind everything.

Comment: Okay it's fixed, but where is top/left attr and the width attribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your header is positioned fixed, it is lifted out of the flow of the document. Therefore it is no longer 'pushing' the nav down, and the nav will appear on top of it as you noticed.

I would suggest you push your nav down by the same amount of pixels as the height of your header. Something like this:

```
.vertical-nav {
   margin-top: 180px;
}
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ar9P6/9/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position:fixed` from your `.header` or change the `z-index` to 0 or more.